# Host not found - Trying to download a csv file using Indy in Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, csv, delphi-xe, indy

I'm trying to download a csv from the .gov.uk website, however, when I run the procedure an error is displayed: Socket Error 11001 Host not found.

```
procedure TFrm_Settings.btn_FetchPricesClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  Url, LocalFile: String;
  FileStrm: TFileStream;
  Http : TIdHTTP;
begin
    Url :=    'http://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/400489/weekly_fuel_prices_csv.csv';
    LocalFile := 'FuelPrices.csv';
    FileStrm := TFileStream.Create(LocalFile, fmCreate);
    Http:= TIDHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      try
        Http.Get(Url, FileStrm);
      finally
        FileStrm.Free;
      end;
   except
     DeleteFile(LocalFile);
     raise;
   end;
```

Comment: That [`request is redirected`](http://i.imgur.com/0QKKWn7.png), so set `Http.HandleRedirects := True` before you perform it. P.S. fix your `try..finally..except` blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I added the Http.HandleRedirects := True, but am still experiencing the same error. I also tried accessing several other csv files, with the same result.

Comment: Could this be due to the fact that the network I am on uses a proxy?

Comment: The error means that the local PC cannot resolve the hostname via DNS.  Since the network is using a proxy, you need to connect `TIdHTTP` to the proxy and let the proxy resolve the DNS.  If the network is using an HTTP proxy, you can fill in the details in the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property. If the network is using a SOCKS proxy, you can assign  a `TIdIOHandlerStack` to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, and then assign a `TIdSocksInfo` to the `IOHandler.TransparentProxy` property.